# How to add space below scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have wrapped an activity in an `scroll view` like following.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/content_form" />

</ScrollView>
```

I have around 15 fields in the `content_form` layout, the issues is that the last item in `content_form` layout is attached with bottom.

I need to add a margin below the scroll view, i have tried giving margin to `scrollview`and the last item of `content_form` field, but nothing is working.

I need to know how to add margin at the bottom of page when using `scroll view`.

Comment: add padding to the bottom of the scroll view. did u try that? or add a view to the button of content_form

Comment: can you add code of content_form

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want the scrolling margin to be within the content, it would be best to add it to `content_form`. You should be able to accomplish this by either adding `paddingBottom` to your parent container in that layout, or `layout_marginBottom` on your last view aligned to the parent bottom.

Answer (score 13):

This make padding under the last item in scroll view. may be good for you

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="80dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Answer (score 7):

You can either use **Space** or **View** for the purpose like

```
<Space
 android:layout_width="100dp"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Or,

```
 <View
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here, you need to give **padding, not margin**.

Try giving padding to the ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with `ScrollView` being ill-behaved when it's direct childview is not a `LinearLayout`. So please try `LinearLayout` as direct child of your `scrollView` and place `<include>` layout inside `LinearLayout`.

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">

      ... your layouts go here ...

   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```